# AVAudioSession Interruption on declining phone call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiosession

I know there are similar questions about AVAudioSession, but mine is a little different.
I have a problem with AVAudioSession interruption.

After declined call, it resumes, but it saves only part recorded after interruption - part before call just dissapears.

For answered calls, even for 1 second it works just fine - it resumes and saves whole recording.

Difference I noticed is when I answer a call, both .began and .ended are called twice, but when I decline a call, it calls only once each one.

Start recording:

```
func startRecording(name:String, quality:AudioQuality, progress:@escaping RecorderProgress, completed:@escaping RecorderCompletion, microphoneProgress:@escaping MicrophoneProgress) {
    log("Recorder - About to start recording")
    if isAudioRecordingGranted {
        self.device = EZMicrophone(microphoneDelegate: self, startsImmediately: true)
        self.name = name
        //Create the session.
        self.recorderProgress = progress
        self.recorderCompletion = completed
        self.microphoneProgress = microphoneProgress
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: session)
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
            try session.setActive(true)
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: audioQuality.rawValue
            ]
            let audioFilename = Directory.documents.appendingPathComponent("\(self.name).m4a")
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            audioRecorder.record()
            isRecording = true
            log("Recorder - Started recording, file at path: \(audioFilename.absoluteString)")
            meterTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector:#selector(update), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
        }
        catch let error {
            completed(error, 0, 0)
            log("Recorder - Error occured while starting audio recording: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Notification handler:

```
@objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let interruptionTypeRawValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
        let interruptionType = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: interruptionTypeRawValue),
        let session = notification.object as? AVAudioSession else {
            log("Recorder - something went wrong")
            return
    }
    switch interruptionType {
    case .began:
        log("Recorder - interruption began")
        try! session.setActive(false)
        audioRecorder.pause()
    case .ended:
        try! session.setActive(true)
        log("Recorder - interruption ended")
    }
}
```

Comment: AVAudioRecorder should handle interruption pause and resume automatically, so maybe it will help if you delete your `handleInterruption` implementation. In any case you should not be deactivating on interruption; that has already happened.

Comment: @matt it pauses automatically, but not resumes. I removed audioRecorder.pause(), but once i resume the problem still occurs

Comment: OK, but then in your `handleInterruption` I don't see _you_ resuming either.

Comment: @matt I'm resuming from button by audioRecorder.resume(), so basically after call, my app is in 'paused' state.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by pausing recording on 'applicationWillResignActive' notification, which calls before interruptions.

Comment: That's an important answer, then; you should answer your own question (and in 48 hours you can accept your own answer).

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to pause recording before it was paused directly from AVAudioSession with CallKit and CXCallObserver delegate function `func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall)` which is called on incoming call.